# Can't interact with UIView, custom drawRect

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I needed a popup/tooltip with a button in my app. After some searching, I decided to use [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView), since it's the closest to what I need visually. Since my code is in Swift, I decided to use the Swift port of the above tooltip:

https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/SwiftPopTipView

Here is the simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
let content = UIView()
content.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)

let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button.setTitle("click me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30)
content.addSubview(button)
button.center = CGPoint(x: content.frame.width / 2, y: content.frame.height/2)

let popup = CMPopTipView(customView: content)
popup.presentPointingAtView(someExistingElement, inView: mainView, animated: false)
```

The tooltip popup appears as expected, the view inside it appears as expected, but the button does not work, `buttonClick` event never gets fired. I've also noticed that if I place this popup above another element, the taps fall through to that element, despite it being blocked by the popup.

Looking at CMPopTipView source code, I don't see anything that would ignore user interaction. In fact, I even tried adding the following to `presentPointingAtView` method of CMPopTipView:

```
containerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
self.userInteractionEnabled = true
self.customView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

The tap still gets ignored by the popup and falls through to the element behind it. Interestingly, the popup also has `disableTapToDismiss` property, which I tried setting to false, and which according to description should dismiss the popup if user clicks anywhere within it. That functionality has no effect either, showing the same symptoms.

Looking further inside CMPopTipView, I see nothing that would affect the way taps are handled (GestureRecognizer, tap pass-through methods, etc.). The only suspicious things I see left are:

- `isAccessibilityElement` in constructor, removing it has no effect
- `backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`, and I heard that sometimes triggers fallthrough, but even changing it to opaque has no effect
- `drawRect` override, this seems like the last remaining culprit, and I'm wondering if by overriding the original `drawRect` the author forgot some mechanism for adding interactive capability back to drawn elements.

If someone could shed more light into this, I'd appreciate it. And if the reason for ignored taps is different, could you please explain?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Just in case, here is an image of how the popup is rendered (in this case I have a bit more styling which I omit in the code above):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you post an image?

Comment: Did you consider delaying the content touches? `self.delaysContentTouches = true`

Comment: @Darko I provided the image, it basically looks almost the same as the screenshots in the github repo I linked, the only difference is the content is clickable.

Comment: @pbush25 I assume self is the `CMPopTipView` element itself? It inherits from `UIView` and doesn't seem to have `delaysContentTouches` property

Comment: Well then you could try to override the hitTest: withEvent method to explicitly tell the touch which view you want it to be interacting with.

Comment: Added the following:

    override public func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        print("hit test")
        return nil
    }

it's not firing on the popup, but it is firing when I click the element that the popup uses as the target

Comment: Just to go sure - you already tried userInteractionEnabled = true on the popup?

Comment: Yes, in the 3 lines of code where I mention `userInteractionEnabled`, self == popup

Comment: I think I may have an idea about what's happening. Since the popup "points" to another UIView, that target UIView may be what the code attaches the popup to, and Cocoa's hit test may be making the assumption that as a child subview of the target, the popup is completely contained within the target UIView, and only running the hit test within those bounds as an optimization. In which case, I need to either attach the popup to something else or tell Cocoa to test the entire screen region when popup is visible.

Comment: That was it, the mainView was actually a subview that happened to render above the popup. Solved the problem by making sure I'm using the root view.